# Joining two DirectoryIterators in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, generator

Suppose I have something like the following:

```
image_data_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_generator = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory(
  'my_directory',
  target_size=(28, 28),
  batch_size=32,
  class_mode='categorical'
)
```

Then my `train_generator` is filled with data from `my_directory`, which contains two subfolders which separate the data into classes `0` and `1`.

Suppose also I have another directory `that_directory`, also with data split into classes `0` and `1`. I want to augment my `train_generator` with this additional data.

Running `train_generator = image_data_generator.flow_from_directory('that_directory', ...)` removes the prior data from `my_directory`.

Is there a way to augment or append both sets of data into one generator or an object that operates like a `DirectoryIterator` without changing the folder structure itself?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just combine the generators in another generator, optionally with different augmentation configs:

```
idg1 = ImageDataGenerator(**idg1_configs)
idg2 = ImageDataGenerator(**idg2_configs)

g1 = idg1.flow_from_directory('idg1_dir',...)
g2 = idg2.flow_from_directory('idg2_dir',...)

def combine_gen(*gens):
    while True:
        for g in gens:
            yield next(g)

# ...
model.fit_generator(combine_gen(g1, g2), steps_per_epoch=len(g1)+len(g2), ...)
```

This would alternately generate batches from `g1` and `g2`.

Note that one might suggest using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), however you can't use that here since `ImageDataGenerators` generators are never-ending and ceaselessly generate batches of data. This is expected for the generator you pass to `fit_generator` method. From [Keras doc](https://keras.io/models/model/#fit_generator):

> ...The generator is expected to loop over its data indefinitely. An epoch finishes when `steps_per_epoch` batches have been seen by the model.

The `steps_per_epoch` if not set would default to `len(generator)` where `generator` is the generator you pass to `fit_generator` method. The `ImageDataGenerator` generators can give their length, so you don't need to manually set the `steps_per_epoch` argument. If you would like the same thing with combined generators above, you can use this solution instead:

```
class CombinedGen():
    def __init__(self, *gens):
        self.gens = gens

    def generate(self):
        while True:
            for g in self.gens:
                yield next(g)

    def __len__(self):
        return sum([len(g) for g in self.gens])

# usage:
cg = CombinedGen(g1, g2)
model.fit_generator(cg.generate(), ...) # no need to set `steps_per_epoch`
```

You can also add `__next__` and/or `__iter__` methods to `CombinedGen` class if you are interested to directly iterate over the objects of this class (instead of iterating over `cg.generate()`).

Comment: How would this work if I am doing something like `for (data, labels) in my_directory_iterator`? It doesn't seem to me that combine_gen would have the nice iterator properties, since it perpetually yields.

Comment: @Richard "...since it perpetually yields" as I said in the last sentence this is how `ImageDataGenerator` works: it just never-endingly generates data. So `combine_gen` is not different. Further, if you carefully read the code you realize it has just wrapped the generators (i.e. it's a wrapper generator), so you can surely do something like `for (data, labels) in combine_gen(*my_generators)`: it would behave the same way (and never stops; you are responsible to stop it somehow with e.g. counting the steps).

Comment: @Richard The limiting is done using `steps_per_epoch` argument of `fit_generator` for `ImageDataGenerator` generators, and you can also use that with `combine_gen()` generators.

Comment: @Richard I just updated my answer with a solution where you don't need to manually set the `steps_per_epoch` argument. Please take a look.

Comment: It turns out that I'm unable to iterate over this because the wrapper doesn't have an __iter__ attribute and doesn't magically inherit it from the underlying DirectoryIterators. It also seems tricky since cg.generate() returns generator objects in Python which I'm not immediately sure how to resolve. This basically got me 90% of the way there, though, and I think it'll work with more patching and more Googling. Thanks!

Comment: @Richard Why don't you iterate over `cg.generate()` instead? It's just a generator. Further, you can easily add `__next__` and/or `__iter__` methods to the `CombinedGen` class if you want to directly iterate over the objects of that class.

Comment: I did end up adding `__next__` and `__iter__` methods to the class but I don't really know how to "resolve" the generator object which is returned. I think I don't really understand how generators work. Do you have a good reference for this?

Quick edit: iterating over `cg.generate()` did indeed work, I think I just wrote really busted `__next__` and `__iter__` methods. I'd still be interested in the reference if you could refer me!

Comment: @Richard Why don't we get help from SO itself?! Here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1756096/2099607), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/231767/2099607), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40255096/2099607), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2776829/2099607), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52056146/2099607). Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Great explaination! I have used this class Combinedgen to combine 5 iterators but I am getting an error unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'Image' and 'float'. The error shows us near yield next(g)........ any reason for that?